# Ruby on Rails - ActionCable - : undefined method `redis_connection_for_subscriptions' for #<ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have recently started working with ActionCable and have managed to get multiple channels working, however when coming to test the channels I have hit a problem.

**Example Channel - subscribe method:**

```
def subscribed
  ActionCable.server.pubsub.redis_connection_for_subscriptions.sadd "#{room.id}_users", current_user.id
  stream_for room
  broadcast_to room, { message: "#{current_user.firstname} is here ...", status: 'joining', id: current_user.id }
end
```

When using the channel in development, the user is added to the redis set. However when testing the channel I run into the following:

**Error**

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'redis_connection_for_subscriptions' for #<ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Test`

I did some digging and found the 'redis_connection_for_subscriptions' method is in rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb#L43

Has anyone came across this issue and found a fix?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: any solution for that? same problem here!